# How do I select a pymol subunit by name?

Tags: pymol

I'm working with 5IVW downloaded from PDB.  This has 5 subunits; each has it's own residue numbering--if I color residues 1-100, 5 sets of residues get colored. If I select atoms with the mouse I see the identification of the subunit: e.g. 5IVW/B/... ; i.e. I've selected atoms in subunit B. But how do I select the subunit, or anything in pymol, by its internal name--so I can just color the residues in subunit B? The documentation has extensive information on selecting by atom, element, residue, etc.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks!  But is there any way to use the e.g. "/5IVW/B/W/ARG`26/CA" nomenclature--evidently the internal representation--in pymol?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the Macromolecules section at [5IVW](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/5ivw). Here,
the six chains (or subunits) in the structure are named **V**, **W**, **0**, **1**, **2**, and **3**.
so your syntax to make a selection called "subunit2" should be:

```
select subunit2, chain W
```

note that in /5ivw/**B**, the B stands for segi-identifier and not the chain or subunit.